# PHP calling method from class into a child of another class

Tags: php, oop, php-5.3

please help me here.
I have a class:

```
class Foo() {
    public function{
        if($var = x){
            do this;
        }
        else {
            do that;
        }
    }
}
```

and another class:

```
class B extends A() {
    public function {
        #need to import method from Foo
        #to execute on a varible in this class

      }
}
```

Could someone please help me out on how to go about this. The language is PHP

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by import?

Comment: If B is extending A, then you can call that A method by simply having `$b = new B(); $b->methodDefinedInA($var_from_B)`

Comment: sorry I meant I need to call a method from class Foo

Comment: If you're saying you want access to a function from Foo in B, you either create a new instance of Foo in B (or call it statically if that's applicable) or have B extend Foo.

Comment: Is B extending Foo or is Foo a seperate class? If so you can make the foo function static and call it in B statically.

Like 
    Foo::Function();

Comment: I need to call a method in Foo. By using require "classFoo.php"

Comment: Foo is a separate class which has methods that need to be called in B. A is extending an abstract class Bar?

Comment: If you're talking about multiple inheritance (i.e. B has access to non-static functions of both A and Foo), PHP doesn't support that (directly). However, you can use traits to simulate it in PHP >= 5.4.

Comment: I get an error --- Fatal error: Call to undefined method B::dothis().Please help

Comment: Hey guys I solved it by declaring the method in Foo static and calling it using its stitically into class B. Thanks guys. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo() {
    public static function test {
        if($var = x) {
            do this;
        }
        else {
            do that;
        }
    }
}


class B extends A() {

    private $variable = 2;

    public function test {
        Foo::test($this->variable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo {
    protected $var;

    function __construct($var) {
        $this->var = $var;
    }

    function test() {
        echo "Method Test from class  Foo<br>";
        if ($this->var == NULL) {
            echo "Test = = Null <br>";
        }
        else {
            echo "Test != = Null <br>";
        }
    }
}

class Ftt extends Foo {
    protected $var1;

    function __construct($var, $var1) {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        parent::__construct($var);
    }

    function test() {
        parent::test();
        echo "Method Test from class Ftt extends Foo";
        echo " with $this->var1  <br>";
    }
}

$ftt = new Ftt('notnull', 'var1');
$ftt->test('notnull');

$foo = new Foo('');
$foo->test();
```